# BIRT reports are not showing query results when deployed

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, birt

I am using BIRT reports for a project I am doing. When I use the web viewer to see a preview of what my report will look like, it looks fine but when I deploy my project, the report just shows column headers but not the data from the queries. I followed the instructions on this page https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-birt-viewer-java-webapps/ but it doesn't seem to want to work. Any suggestions as to what I may be doing wrong or what I may have missed would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Kalkrin. My first throught is about the JDBC. When you created the report, did you use a special JDBC?

Comment: What do you mean a special JDBC?. Sorry I just don't understand what you mean by a special one.

Comment: When you created your report. You added a data source. In this data source : what is the Driver class (in the BIRT JDBC Data source tab)?

Comment: Can we have the logs?